# displaying poll data on ExpressionEngine site

Tags: module, expressionengine

I'm using the eeHarbor polls module and need help with the following:

As the code is currently configured, the poll question displays on my homepage. If the user either selects an option and casts a vote, or clicks on the "view results" option, the results are then displayed within the same area on the homepage (replacing the poll questions and options).

I would like to have the results (either after a vote is cast or after the user selects "view results") displayed on a different page, where I can add related content. Does anyone know how I may edit the poll module's parameters to make this happen?

Also, the poll module creates all new polls with 2 possible voting options/answers. There is a link to click that should allow the admin to "add options" or "add other option" but clicking this link doesn't dork, leaving me with only 2 options for every poll.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the module with no change.

Any ideas why this is happening and how it may be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Check the FAQ page here: http://eeharbor.com/polls/faq

Can I change the return URL for a given poll?
Yes, as of version 1.4 you can add a hidden form element with the name of "return_url" to specify the url you would like a user to be sent to after submitting a poll.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="" />
```